# Labeling a matrix using python numpy library

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, labeling

I know that we can use Pandas for labeling the rows and columns of a matrix. But I want to use numpy to label rows and columns of a matrix.

Let me define the problem using a matrix
Suppose I am initilaizing a bigger size matrix: 16x16

```
import numpy as np
C = np.zeros((16, 16), dtype=int)
```

Also, I have 2 small size matrix: say A and B: both are 8x8

then, what I need is this:

```
C[0:4, 0:4] = A[0:4, 0:4]
C[0:4, 4:8] = A[0:4, 4:8]
C[4:8, 0:4] = A[4:8, 0:4]
C[4:8, 4:8] = A[4:8, 4:8] + B[0:4, 0:4]
```

something like this.. can I do the same operation with little labeling and automation?

Comment: Define `a=slice(0,4)` then `C[a,a]=A[a,a]` and so forth.

Comment: Also with `aa = (a,a)` a tuple,  `C[aa] = A[aa]`

Comment: Let me clarify it a bit more:Like in Pandas we can label rows and columns and if I have to modify a piece of matrix, I can do that.. can I do the same while using Numpy library using labels?

Comment: No, numpy does not use labels like pandas.  indexes are strictly plositional.

Comment: You might get more help if you showed how `pandas` labeling would make that task any easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear what exactly you are looking for, but you make your code a bit more concise with

```
C[0:8, 0:8] = A[0:8, 0:8]
C[4:8, 4:8] += B[0:4, 0:4]
```